# Service apache2 is running but not responding CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, centos, apache2, freetds

I tried to run a CentOS Apache2 / PHP / MySQL server on a LAN (With 10.x.x.x IP).

**OS : CentOS release 6.7 (Final)**

I checked if the services is running, they're still working.

```
[root@srv-annuaire-01 ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd status
httpd (pid  2542) en cours d'exÃ©cution... *(running)*
[root@srv-annuaire-01 ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld status
mysqld (pid  1795) en cours d'exÃ©cution... *(running)*
```

Edit : That's the service iptables who's blocking us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apache2 config file add

```
listen port_no
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

and restart your server